# Using "NOT" in a jquery nth-child formula

Tags: jquery

I'd LIKE to remove the 3rd, 4th, 6th, 7th, 9th, etc **TH**.
I thought I could do something like:

```
  summaryHead.find('tr:first th:nth-child(!3n+2)').remove;
```

however it doesn't work.
I also tried

```
summaryHead.find('tr:first th:nth-child(3n+3)').remove();
summaryHead.find('tr:first th:nth-child(3n+4)').remove();
```

This behaves rather weirdly. Is there a way to combine two finds?

For clarity I want to remove all of the green and red fields in this image, sometimes there might be more or less rooms, but each room will have 3 fields, and I want to give the first room's field `colspan 3` and hide the 2 extra fields (colored red & green here):
[image]

Comment: Your pattern seems confusing. Can you show it clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a nicer way but you can always do something like this

```
summaryHead.find('tr:first th').filter(':nth-child(3n+3), :nth-child(3n+4)').remove();
```

Comment: Close! `summaryHead.find('tr:first').find('th:nth-child(3n+3), th:nth-child(3n+4)').remove();` does the trick! Thanks.

Comment: @smnbbrv you should use `.filter` instead of `.find` since you have already selected the `th` elements.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli absolutely right, thank you for a good point

Answer (score 1):

if the `3n+2` is the ones you want to keep you can use the `:not`

```
summaryHead.find('tr:first th:not(:nth-child(3n+2))').remove();
```

Your second attempt does not work, because the second `find` you run works on the already edited group (*the elements from he previous step have been removed so it would not target what you think*)

Comment: Close but this does remove the first child as well. Pity as this is shorter code.

Comment: true, i was only translating your `('tr:first th:nth-child(!3n+2)')` to a working version.